# Synonym [electricity] and [electrical]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Saw this HNQ [post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/214429/where-to-check-for-neighbors-stealing-power) about neighbors stealing electricity. But we already have [electrical](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical), which better fits with the site.

I have [proposed a synonym](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) and would appreciate votes on it.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with tag synonyms. But in looking at this, I saw a suggestion for ac->hvac. I think there were 12 ac questions, 1 already had air-conditioning, 2 really meant "alternating current" (I changed one of those to electrical) and the others I changed to air-conditioning. IMHO, not a synonym candidate (for air-conditioning or hvac) because of confusion with "alternating current".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Really we need a separate question for that, but I would say we should make an [alternating-current] for that then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the proposal. I've gone ahead and approved the electricity -> electrical synonym.